# Cant open software center

Tags: software-center

When i try to open sofware center i get this message and wont open, can you please help me to find the error?

```
jdash@ubuntu:~$ software-center
2013-01-22 18:38:08,149 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-01-22 18:38:08,152 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-01-22 18:38:08,395 - softwarecenter.config - WARNING - Could not read the config file '/home/jdash/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg': File contains no section headers.
file: d, line: 1
u'Help on method triangular in module random:\n'
2013-01-22 18:38:08,396 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2013-01-22 18:38:08,487 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - show_available_packages: search_text is '', app is None.
2013-01-22 18:38:08,738 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 176, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1422, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1352, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 154, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 136, in init_view
    SoftwarePane.init_view(self)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/softwarepane.py", line 215, in init_view
    self.icons, self.show_ratings)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appview.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.helper = AppPropertiesHelper(db, cache, icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/models/appstore2.py", line 109, in __init__
    softwarecenter.paths.APP_INSTALL_PATH)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 255, in parse_applications_menu
    category = self._parse_menu_tag(child)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 440, in _parse_menu_tag
    l = self._parse_directory_tag(element)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 305, in _parse_directory_tag
    cp.read(fname)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/update.py", line 535, in read
    RawConfigParser.read(self, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser.py", line 710, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/configparser.py", line 1093, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: d, line: 1
u'Help on method triangular in module random:\n'
```

This is the content of the file Mark:

```
[general]
maximized = False
size = 1200, 800
add_to_launcher = True
recommender_uuid = 
recommender_profile_id =
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a good idea to post the contents of the file:

`cat /home/jdash/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg`

You could also try renaming the file and seeing if it is recreated the next time you try to open it. To do this run this from the command line:

`mv /home/jdash/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg /home/jdash/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg.backup`

If that does not work then you can revert the change with:

`mv /home/jdash/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg.backup /home/jdash/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg`

You'll be back where you started but it's worth a go. If this doesn't work then post the contents of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try removing software center and reinstalling it:

`sudo apt-get remove software-center`

then re-install it with:

`sudo apt-get install software-center`

Comment: already done that, didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the file should look something like this:

```
[general]
maximized = False
size = 1088, 800
add_to_launcher = True
recommender_uuid = 
recommender_profile_id = 
accepted_tos = yes

[reviews]
username = jdash
```

If you run:

`nano /home/jdash/.config/software-center/softwarecenter.cfg`
and paste the above in
`ctrl+shift+v` to paste then `ctrl+x` to quit.. make sure you save, hopefully that will work

Comment: didn't work either =(

Comment: can you edit your question to show the output from the terminal when you try to start software center now with this configuration?

Comment: Ok, just edited question with the new output.

Comment: That looks like the same output as the original. Have you ever been able to use the software center?

Comment: yes, i was able.

Comment: could you give me the output of this command please: `ls -l ~/.config/software-center/`

Comment: total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jdash jdash 161 ene 22 18:34 softwarecenter.cfg

Answer (score 0):

Use synaptic package manager instead?

to install: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

to run: `sudo synaptic`

Comment: ok installed. what should i do now in synaptic?

Comment: It's a package manager, it can be used in place of the software centre, it's less clunky and has more to choose from, it can be used until you figure out what is wrong.